# Webbrowser control takes 20- 60 seconds to load a page for the first time

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer-11, webbrowser-control

When using a webbrower control it takes between 20 and 60 second to load any page it hasn't loaded previously.

I'm using VB.net on VS2017. I've changed my registry to allow the webbrowser control to use IE11 (installed).

I've set up a very small, simple test to try and identify the problem. Here's the code:

```
Dim bool As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If bool = False Then
        bool = True
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.bbc.co.uk")
    Else
        bool = False
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com")
    End If

End Sub
```

It's just a simple way to navigate from one URL to another and then back between the two. I've used the webbrowser control in the past and not had this issue, the speed has always been comparable to the loading times of the normal IE browser. My internet speeds are fine (normal IE browser loads pages in less than a second), the issue only occurs with the webbrowser control. It happens in any project I create (hence not based on any other project settings), I've tried it in both debug and release, on both x32 and x64 targets. When loading either of the pages above it'll take between 20 and 60 seconds for either of them the first time, after they have both been loaded they will then load in a fraction of the time. If I restart debugging then the issue reoccurs until I've loaded them both again.

My true use case of this will be loading many different URLs, only once. I have no idea how to fix this, or even where to begin... I'll take advice, questions, suggestions, even alters to sacrifice at, at this point. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it help if you use `"https://www.bbc.co.uk"`, i.e. specify the protocol?

Comment: @AndrewMorton just tried it, it behaves the same :/

Comment: Has it only had this problem since you changed the registry to get it to use IE11? Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: Nope, I changed the registery in the hopes that would fix the issue. No proxy :/

Comment: I tried the code in your question and there was no excessive delay for me. Could it be your antivirus software getting in the way? With most of them, you can exclude a directory, such as the one your program is in. Does anything happen to use a lot of CPU time in Task Manager when your program loads one of those sites the first time?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've tried with both my antivirus off (for a quick check) and with the directory the application is in added to the antivirus exceptions. Nothing unusual goes to the top of CPU usage (and nothing stays there for more than a fraction of a second). Thanks for your help with this btw. Still no solution though :/